# How to enforce a specific partitioning and sort order automatically with a UDAF in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, partitioning

I think the title of the question is quite clear. Based on the [documentation regarding custom UDAFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html), I want to develop a UDAF which uses a certain algorithm that relies on the fact that the `reduce(b: BUF, a: IN): BUF` function is called for inputs that are partitioned and sorted on the field that is being aggregated. And if this is not the case, I would like this to be enforced based on the fact that I'm using this UDAF, rather than repartitioning and sorting manually.

For example:
If I were to develop my own `my_count_distinct`; say I'm calling it like this:
`my_count_distinct("user_id")`.

- The `reduce` would increment a counter in the buffer when the current `user_id` is different than the previous one, as the algorithm assumes the the input is ordered on `user_id`.
- The `merge` would just simply add up the counters in the buffer since the assumption is that the DataFrame is partitioned on the `user_id`, therefore the input per partition should be mutually exclusive.